# Captured image viewpoint changing

Tags: image, image-processing, transform, vision

i have a picture that captured from a fixed position [X Y Z] and angle [Pitch Yaw Roll] and a focal length of F (i think this information is called camera matrix)

[image]

i want to change the captured picture to a different position like it was taken in up position

the result image should be like:

[image]

in fact i have picture taken from this position:

[image]

and i want to change my picture in a way that it was taken in this position:

[image]

i hope that i could express my problem.

thnx in advance

Comment: From where do you have those images? Are they generated in your application somehow or they are just input images?

Comment: actually the first image is the imputed image from a camera and the second one should be the output of my program. 3 and 4 is just for demonstrating my purpose.

Comment: Is this for a school project?

Comment: no it is for robocup (humanoid league).

Comment: Doing this with any semblance of accuracy is only possible in the Law & Order Crime Labs.  Pay attention to your question titles btw, you won't get many views when you murder them like that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done accurately only for the (green) plane itself. The 3D objects standing onto the plane will be deformed after remapping, but the deformation may be acceptable if their height is small relative to the camera distance.

If the camera is never moving, all you need to do is identify on the perspective image four points that are the four vertices of a rectangle of known size (e.g. the soccer field itself), then compute the [homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) that maps those four points to that rectangle, and apply it to the whole image.

For details and code, see the OpenCV links at the bottom of that Wikipedia article.